# Visual Basic Variable within a variable name

Tags: arrays, vb.net, variables

In VB I would like to call an array, based on an integer value from a textbox.

Arrays are named as follows: arr1, arr2, arr3, etc.

So,

```
Dim num1 as Integer = TextBox1.Text
```

If num1 = 6, then in the code below, I want it to call arr6.

```
TextBox1.AppendText(arr(num1))
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not dynamic variable names in .NET (like PHP or other scripting languages). Also, you should make sure that `TextBox1.Text` is actually an integer or you will throw an exception.

```
Dim num1 as Integer
If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, num1) then
'some logic here because it parsed, otherwise its not a number!

end if
```

You could use a List or other generic collection to hold your arrays and reference them by their index in the list if you really need arrays all "named" differently.

```
Dim lst As New List(Of Integer())

Dim arr1 As Integer() = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Dim arr2 As Integer() = {2, 4, 6, 8, 9}
lst.Add(arr1)
lst.Add(arr2)

dim arrToUse as Integer() = lst.Item(num1)
```

Comment: What a shame. I thought I was just not using the correct brackets, or braces. I guess I will look for a workaround. Thanks for the suggestion!